# jQuery add css style

Tags: jquery

I have this text string and I would like to replace it with new text string but everytime I do it the css of it was gone. And then I make a script to add the css back but it doesn't seem to work. Any help please?

```
jQuery('div:contains("text")').replaceWith('newText').css({font-weight:"bolder"});
```

Thanks

Comment: Please post your HTML code.

Answer (score 4):

use `.text()` instead:

```js
jQuery('div:contains(text)').text('newText').css({"font-weight":"bolder"});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>text</div>
```

`.replaceWith()` method replaces the element with the `textNode` in your code and `font-weight` css property should have to be wrapped in either quotes or use camelCase naming convention `fontWeight`.

Comment: _the question was about the css not working :P although it's fixed in your code_ never mind you fixed it

Comment: @TecHunter congrats you've also done that and the question was not just about css. There is an issue with the logic OP thought He/She will update the div with the new string value but unfortunately that was replacing it.

Comment: my bad, the title was too explicit was focused on the css part but also noticed the text. anyway this was really trivial...

Answer (score 0):

[Please read the api](http://api.jquery.com/css/) and also [this one](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

You need to change it to :

```
jQuery('div:contains("text")').text('newText').css({fontWeight:"bolder"});
```

`.text()` to change the text content, `.html()` same but without escaping html

`.css` takes camelHump case for properties. so instead of `font-weight` use `'fontWeight'` or `'font-weight'`

> Also, jQuery can equally interpret the CSS and DOM formatting of multiple-word properties. For example, jQuery understands and returns the correct value for both .css( "background-color" ) and .css( "backgroundColor" ). This means mixed case has a special meaning, .css( "WiDtH" ) won't do the same as .css( "width" ), for example.

Comment: I get this now. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

if you create a  tag linking to a stylesheet and add it to the  tag, the browser will load that stylesheet.

```
  $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lightbox_stylesheet.css">');
```